# Character encoding used by sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr

Tags: sql, t-sql, encoding, csv

I am taking a backup of my dataset as a csv.
However, one of the table contains a binary field. I came across this function, sys.fn_sqlvarbasetostr, provided by MS SQL but I cant find which character encoding this will use.

If you know any other approach to do this, plz let me know.

***Edit***:-

We ended up doing this in c#, but I am still marking Alex's answer as correct because if I was to do this through SQL queries then his answer will work.

Approach we ended up with:-
For binary column csv contains a hex value, so an example row looks like 'somename','someothertext', 2bcd8 (hex representing binary data).
Initially we were not writing hex data properly. 0x3d455 failed, '0xa2342' failed, '3444d' failed, 2bcd8 SUCCESS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2008 you can convert to a string directly;

```
declare @b varbinary(1024) = 0xDEADBEEFF00D
select convert(varchar(1024), @b, 1) + ','

>>0xDEADBEEFF00D,
```

**SQL2k:**

```
declare @base   binary(6)   set @base = 0xB00BB00BB00B
declare @aschar varchar(14) set @aschar = dbo.fn_sqlvarbasetostr(@base)

select 'as string: ' + @aschar

--convert back to binary
declare @bin binary(6)
declare @sql nvarchar(512) = 'set @bin=convert(binary(6),' + @aschar + ')'
execute sp_executesql @sql, N'@bin binary(6) output', @bin=@bin output

select 'as binary:', @bin, case when @bin = @base then 'ok' end
```

For

```
>>as string: 0xb00bb00bb00b
>>as binary: 0xB00BB00BB00B  ok
```

Comment: and just wondering (because of my limited knowledge of character encoding)..is it safe to convert it into hex string without knowing the character encoding being used? can this hex string be later converted back to same binary data?

Comment: Converting like that should be fine, its just a string representation of every byte in the binary field, to decode it back to varbinary just `convert(varbinary(1024), '0xDEADBEEFF00D', 1)`

Comment: damn! Their db is using an old version of sql...its sql server 2000!

Comment: Is fn_sqlvarbasetostr available? Its the same, just a 1:1 representation of the bytes

Comment: that function is available but cant find its reverse function which can take a hex and put it in binary

Comment: Depends how you intend to revert; there is convert(binary(x), 0xBEEF) for literal (unquoted) binary values; added example above for string values

Comment: we ended up doing this in c#, for binary column csv contains a hex value, so an example row looks like 'somename','someothertext', 2bcd8 (hex representing binary data). Initially we were not writing hex data properly. 0x3d455 failed, '0xa2342' failed, '3444d' failed, 2bcd8 SUCCESS!